# Setup and use parameters in PHPUnit data providers

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I'm trying to write tests for a service which uses global parameters (from YML files).

I'm retrieving this parameters in the `setUp()` method, but when I try to use them in a `@dataProvider`, it throws an error.

```
class InterpreterServiceTest extends KernelTestCase
{
    private $container;
    private $service;
    private $citiesMap;

    public function setUp()
    {
        self::bootKernel();
        $this->container = self::$kernel->getContainer();
        $this->service = $this->container->get('geolocation.interpreter');
        $this->citiesMap = $this->container->getParameter("citiesmap");
        self::tearDown();
    }

    /**
     * @dataProvider locationsProvider
     */
    public function testCompanyCityFromCity($location, $expected)
    {
        $city = $this->service->getCompanyCityFromCity($location);
        $this->assertEquals($expected, $city);
    }

    public function locationsProvider()
    {
        $return = array();
        foreach ($this->citiesMap as $area) {
            $return[] = [
                $area['external_service_area'],
                $area['company_area']
            ];
        }
        return $return;
    }
}
```

> **Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**

If I manually write the return of `locationsProvider()` it works

```
return [
    ["Barcelona", "Barcelona"],
    ["Madrid", "Madrid"],
    ["Cartagena", "Murcia"]
];
```

I also have checked the foreach in `setUp()` and it returns the proper expected array.

---

It seems the `@dataProvider` is executed **before** the `setUp()` method.

Is there a different way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Afraid you have to get all your data (incl. service obj) inside the `dataProvider` method

**TL&DR** This should do it:

```
class InterpreterServiceTest extends KernelTestCase
{
    /**
     * @dataProvider locationsProvider
     */
    public function testCompanyCityFromCity($service, $location, $expected)
    {
        $city = $service->getCompanyCityFromCity($location);

        $this->assertEquals($expected, $city);
    }

    public function locationsProvider()
    {
        self::bootKernel();

        $container = self::$kernel->getContainer();
        $service = $this->container->get('geolocation.interpreter');
        $citiesMap = $this->container->getParameter("citiesmap");
        // self::tearDown(); - depends on what is in the tearDown

        $return = array();
        foreach ($citiesMap as $area) {
            $return[] = [
                $service,
                $area['external_service_area'],
                $area['company_area']
            ];
        }

        return $return;
    }
}
```

**Why:**

Both `setUp` and `setUpBeforeClass` methods are run inside the `run` method of the `PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite` class.
However, data from the `dataProvider` is calculated earlier as part of `createTest` function.

Comment: I defined a `_configured` flag and I will call `setUp` from each dataProvider, so it will only run the first time it's called. Now I can add or remove any dataProvider, and the original setUp will be working even if I don't call it from any dataProvider.

Comment: This is also the reason why data-providers must be publicly available or could be from a different class.

Comment: I had to add self::ensureKernelShutdown() to the end of the provider for this solution to work

Comment: I'm unable to get the parameter_bag using this method.  The error is that it has been removed or inlined.  Nor am I able to AutoWire anything in the constructor.  Any suggestions?